# Make a logger for Node Js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, winston

I have a project in Node Js, which executes the project on port 3000 and I access from ngrok with my browser to said localhost port, and it executes a server on port 3001 to make requests to a Maria database db. The project is done in react and the server with express.

I want to save the application logs (errors, warnings, etc.) in a log file so that I can see them whenever I want.

My intention was to use winston, and while I have no problem on the server side (3001), when I try to adapt it to the main project, I get an error that it cannot save files (the reason that appears is that it runs from the browser, and you can't create such a file because you don't have access to the project folders)

Can anyone give me some advice? Am I wrong to use winston, and should I use another?

Greetings and thanks

Comment: Server doesn't run on browsers. If you implemented logger in front then Error will appear

Answer (score 0):

I've never used winston before and I couldn't find anything online about your error. In the past I've always just used node's fs module to create a log of errors and restarts.

```
const fs = require('fs')
```

Node's File System Documentation: https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-fs-module

Short YouTube Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U57kU311-nE